ExcelWriter throws TypeInitializationException when trying to run the AutoFitWidth function
SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter has the capability to create a worksheet area based on a number of columns. This works, however, when I try to AutoFitWidth() of the Area I receive this error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.Parser.NumberFormatting.Pieces.NumberFormatterParser' threw an exception.  and it has the following Inner Exception: MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Antlr4.Runtime.Atn.ATN Antlr4.Runtime.Atn.ATNDeserializer.Deserialize(Char[])'.
This is in an ASP.NET MVC 5 .NET 4.8 web application. The application has the proper references to the SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.dll (Version 12.0.7.455) and the ANTLR4.Runtime.Standard.dll (Version 4.13.1).
Here is the code that is throwing the error:
ExcelApplication xla = ExcelHelper.getExcelApplication();

string file = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/" + file_name);

Workbook wb = xla.Open(file);
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

GlobalStyle styleData = wb.CreateStyle();
styleData.NumberFormat = "$#.##00";

GlobalStyle styleHeader = wb.CreateStyle();
styleHeader.Font.Bold = true;
styleHeader.BackgroundColor = wb.Palette.GetClosestColor(88, 19, 130);
styleHeader.Font.Color = wb.Palette.GetClosestColor(255, 255, 255);

GlobalStyle styleMoney = wb.CreateStyle();
styleMoney.NumberFormat = "$* #,##0";

GlobalStyle styleDateTime = wb.CreateStyle();
styleDateTime.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";

GlobalStyle styleTime = wb.CreateStyle();
styleTime.NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss";


var colcount = Model.Columns.Count;
var thetype = "";

//if (file_name == "blank.xlsx")
{
    //get headers
    for (int i = 0; i <= colcount - 1; i++)
    {
        ws.Cells[0, i].Value = Model.Columns[i];
    }

    Area header = ws.CreateArea(0, 0, 1, colcount);
    header.ApplyStyle(styleHeader);

}
var dk = "";

for (int j = 0; j <= Model.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k <= colcount - 1; k++)
    {
        if (k == 11)
        {
            dk = fn.NullToString(Model.Rows[j][k]);
        }
        ws.Cells[j + 1, k].Value = Model.Rows[j][k];
    }
}

//apply styles
for (int i = 0; i <= colcount - 1; i++)
{
    thetype = Model.Columns[i].DataType.Name.ToString();
    switch (thetype)
    {
        case "DateTime":
            ws.GetColumnProperties(i).ApplyStyle(styleDateTime);
            break;
        case "Money":
            ws.GetColumnProperties(i).ApplyStyle(styleMoney);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}


//look for titles to show dollar signs
for (int i = 0; i <= colcount - 1; i++)
{
    string colname = Model.Columns[i].ToString();
    if(colname.Contains("($)"))
    {
        ws.GetColumnProperties(i).ApplyStyle(styleMoney);
    }
}


//autofit
Area a = ws.CreateAreaOfColumns(0, colcount);
a.AutoFitWidth();

